# Facebook Audience Network not displaying test Ads. Already added TestDevice

Tags: android

I created a new sample project for displaying the Facebook audience network Banner ad at bottom of my activity.

My app is running in device but not displaying anything at bottom. I already added the hash for test device.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package liveradio.radioz.com.facebookads;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.facebook.ads.*;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private AdView adView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        adView = new AdView(this, "PLACEMENT-ID", AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);

        // Find the Ad Container
        LinearLayout adContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.banner_container);

        // Add the ad view to your activity layout
        adContainer.addView(adView);
        AdSettings.addTestDevice("DEVICE-ID");

        // Request an ad
        adView.loadAd();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (adView != null) {
            adView.destroy();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="liveradio.radioz.com.facebookads.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/banner_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="liveradio.radioz.com.facebookads">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Log :**

```
01/12 12:13:01: Launching app
$ adb shell am start -n "liveradio.radioz.com.facebookads/liveradio.radioz.com.facebookads.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -D
Waiting for application to come online: liveradio.radioz.com.facebookads.test | liveradio.radioz.com.facebookads
Waiting for application to come online: liveradio.radioz.com.facebookads.test | liveradio.radioz.com.facebookads
Waiting for application to come online: liveradio.radioz.com.facebookads.test | liveradio.radioz.com.facebookads
Connecting to liveradio.radioz.com.facebookads
Waiting for application to start debug server
Waiting for application to come online: liveradio.radioz.com.facebookads.test | liveradio.radioz.com.facebookads
Connecting to liveradio.radioz.com.facebookads
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8645', transport: 'socket'
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
I/zygote: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
W/zygote: Suspending all threads took: 83.944ms
W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 9752(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 61% free, 973KB/2MB, paused 48.188ms total 236.235ms
W/ActivityThread: Application liveradio.radioz.com.facebookads is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/zygote: Debugger is active
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1486)
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
I/WebViewFactory: Loading com.android.chrome version 61.0.3163.98 (code 316409812)
I/zygote: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
I/cr_LibraryLoader: Time to load native libraries: 3 ms (timestamps 6510-6513)
I/chromium: [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(136)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
I/cr_LibraryLoader: Expected native library version number "61.0.3163.98", actual native library version number "61.0.3163.98"
E/FBAudienceNetwork: You don't call AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(). Some functionality may not work properly.
D/IS_UNITY: false
D/AdInternalSettings: Test mode device hash: 877dd37b-fff7-4fa1-b83d-776592220359
D/AdInternalSettings: When testing your app with Facebook's ad units you must specify the device hashed ID to ensure the delivery of test ads, add the following code before loading an ad: AdSettings.addTestDevice("877dd37b-fff7-4fa1-b83d-776592220359");
D/IS_UNITY: false
E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.facebook.katana.provider.AttributionIdProvider
D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
V/StudioProfiler: StudioProfilers agent attached.
V/StudioProfiler: Acquiring Application for Events
V/StudioProfiler: Transformed class: java/net/URL
W/zygote: Current dex file has more than one class in it. Calling RetransformClasses on this class might fail if no transformations are applied to it!
V/StudioProfiler: Memory control stream started.

                  [ 01-12 12:13:06.606 20774:20877 D/         ]
                  HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd1835a80, tid 20877
I/zygote: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe4b85540: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe4b85540: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe4b83360)
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe4b85540: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe4b83360)
W/cr_ChildProcLH: Create a new ChildConnectionAllocator with package name = com.android.chrome, sandboxed = true
I/cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=false

                     [ 01-12 12:13:07.026 20774:20774 D/         ]
                     HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xd1583c00, tid 20774
D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xcecec360: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xcecec360: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe21fff60)
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/cr_CrashFileManager: /data/user/0/liveradio.radioz.com.facebookads/cache/WebView/Crash Reports does not exist or is not a directory
W/com.facebookads: type=1400 audit(0.0:22): avc: denied { read } for name="vmstat" dev="proc" ino=4026532039 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:proc:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
D/IS_UNITY: false
I/zygote: Background concurrent copying GC freed 7886(1025KB) AllocSpace objects, 5(100KB) LOS objects, 50% free, 1746KB/3MB, paused 680us total 122.639ms
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=30KB, data=25KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=30KB, data=25KB
I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
V/StudioProfiler: Live memory tracking disabled.
V/StudioProfiler: Live memory tracking enabled.
V/StudioProfiler: JNIEnv not attached
V/StudioProfiler: Loaded classes: 6311
V/StudioProfiler: Tracking initialization took: 648527000ns
I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=60KB, data=44KB
I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=56KB, data=43KB
I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8645', transport: 'socket'
```

I'm getting the build successful and installed in my device. When I open the app I can't see any ads or test ads at bottom of my main activity.

Comment: Don't add code-snippets for every lang, they are only meant for HTML, CSS and JS

Comment: Sorry. first time mistake

Comment: And I think you should remove your banner id from question

Comment: Yea Zlytherin, I removed it

Answer (score 5):

If you've added Audience network libraries, you can add the code below to show test ads without worrying about adding a test device.

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            AdSettings.setTestMode(true);
}
```

Add this code, preferably in your Application class.

Answer (score 1):

First Implement this library:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.99.1'
```

than use below code:

```
com.facebook.ads.AdView adView;
adView = new com.facebook.ads.AdView(this, "PLACEMENT-ID", 
com.facebook.ads.AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);

((LinearLayout) adContainer).addView(adView);
adView.loadAd();
```

Answer (score 0):

first, add this library to your grade file

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.12.0'
```

then paste this code in your xml file

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/banner_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        />
```

In your Java code paste this code and also replace IMG_16_9_APP_INSTALL#YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID with your banner ad ID

```
    adView = new AdView(this, "IMG_16_9_APP_INSTALL#YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID", AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);
LinearLayout adContainer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.banner_container);
adContainer.addView(adView);
adView.loadAd();
```

for more information you can follow official link of meta
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/setting-up/ad-setup/android/banner

Answer (score 0):

According to the Logcat messages, it seems you are just forgetting to initialize the SDK.

```
E/FBAudienceNetwork: You don't call AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(). Some functionality may not work properly.
```